# DataContext.Refresh takes extremely long

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am working with relatively big database in C# that uses LINQ to SQL, where the following LINQ method is used to refresh a table before displaying the information:

```
using System.Data.Linq;
//ExpressDB is the database currently being used
//"Bookings" is a table in the db
ExpressDBDataContext db = new ExpressDBDataContext();
public void RefreshBookings() { db.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, db.Bookings); }
```

`RefreshBookings()`takes roughly 10-12 seconds with current database, so I would like to know if there is a faster or more efficient way of doing this without taking as much processing time.

**UPDATE:** I found that re-initialising the Database takes significantly less time than using DataContext.Refresh, is that a good solution?

Comment: Check the SQL query which was generated underneath, then check the Execution Plan of the query.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is there any quick way to do that? I tried using LINQpad but I couldn't figure out how to call LINQ methods.

Comment: Which LINQ methods were you trying to call?

Comment: Note that your call will load all of `db.Bookings` into memory and then query the database for every Booking, which I doubt is what you want?

Comment: For example, try `Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, Bookings)` in a query attached to your database using LINQ to SQL (not EF) and examine the SQL tab.